# how to update field amps when thickness is between 'xxx'

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

I am trying to follow the normalization rules when designing tables. 
For this query i am trying to update the settings.amps (in multiple rows), to a value when the thickness is between a range, in this case between 5 and 10 incl.

[image: table structure]

I can select all the setting.id rows correctly with a select statement but when trying to convert to an update statement, error near from keeps coming up

this query correctly selects the rows i am after

```
SELECT
    s.id AS setting_id,
    s.amps AS setting_amps
FROM
    setting AS s
JOIN materials AS m ON
    s.material_id = m.id
JOIN material_thickness AS mt ON
    m.thickness_id = mt.id
WHERE
    mt.thickness BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

this is the attempt at an update

```
UPDATE
    setting
SET
    amps = 65
FROM
    setting AS s
JOIN materials AS m ON
    s.material_id = m.id
JOIN material_thickness AS mt ON
    m.thickness_id = mt.id
WHERE
    mt.thickness BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

Comment: What's 65, where should it come from?

Comment: 65 is the amps.value im trying to set all the rows to where the thickness is between 5 and 10

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use joins in an UPDATE statement in SQLite.
What you can do is something like this:

```
UPDATE setting
SET amps = 65
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM materials AS m   
  JOIN material_thickness AS mt 
  ON m.thickness_id = mt.id
  WHERE
    m.id = setting.material_id
    AND
    mt.thickness BETWEEN 5 AND 10
)
```

You use EXISTS to check whether a row should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery ( *Considering the fixed constant value 65* )

```
UPDATE
    setting
   SET
    amps = ( SELECT 65
               FROM materials AS m              
               JOIN material_thickness AS mt
                 ON m.thickness_id = mt.id 
              WHERE setting.material_id = m.id
                AND mt.thickness BETWEEN 5 AND 10 )
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 65
               FROM materials AS m              
               JOIN material_thickness AS mt
                 ON m.thickness_id = mt.id 
              WHERE setting.material_id = m.id
                AND mt.thickness BETWEEN 5 AND 10 )
```

or even better method,without repeating the subquery, which uses `with..as` including your original query

```
WITH T AS
(
 SELECT
    s.id AS setting_id,
    s.amps AS setting_amps
   FROM
    setting AS s
   JOIN materials AS m ON
    s.material_id = m.id
   JOIN material_thickness AS mt ON
    m.thickness_id = mt.id
  WHERE
    mt.thickness BETWEEN 5 AND 10
)
UPDATE setting
   SET amps = 65
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE setting_id = setting.id)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=a4361aba0121dbc4dc4a36bcf0fefad6)</kbd>

Comment: cheers, all the fields in all the tables are set to not null.  I get the error - SQL Error [19]: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (NOT NULL constraint failed: setting.amps)

Comment: @joeblogs Perhaps we need to add an exists part to restrict matching.